# Compatibility with IE 10 for Windows 7

Tags: internet-explorer, cross-browser

I am new to compatibility for IE. I was recently put on a project for my company and need to fix an issue that just started yesterday. Microsoft created IE10 for windows 7 and for some reason the compatibility view does now work on our page anymore. In IE 9 and IE10 for Window 8 the compatibility works fine.

The page in question currently is referencing this DOCTYPE

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

I understand that this is not the best DOCTYPE since it is not even using the strict standards but to change it to strict now causes the page to display incorrectly. I am in the process of recoding the whole page to make it better compatible with current versions of IE and eventually with other broswers.

Please note that the page consists of coldfusion, Javascript, HTML and is a form.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Cold Fusion, but you can tell IE to use a render mode by making sure that your response header contains the following:

```
X-UA-Compatible: IE=8
```

The above tells IE to render using IE8 mode.

Alternatively, you can specify the above information using a meta tag, per [Specifying legacy document modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Use Internet Explorer 9 Standards mode -->
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9">
  <title>My webpage</title>
</head>
```